# Flex: -frames.frame

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Has anyone used this successfully or found further documentation than just the below (from the [Adobe site](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html)):

> **frames.frame label class_name [...]**
>
> Specifies a SWF file frame label with
>    a sequence of class names that are
>    linked onto the frame.
>
> This option lets you add asset
>    factories that stream in after the
>    application that then publish their
>    interfaces with the ModuleManager
>    class. The advantage to doing this is
>    that the application starts faster
>    than it would have if the assets had
>    been included in the code, but does
>    not require moving the assets to an
>    external SWF file.
>
> This is an advanced option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting article [here](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=FF295F89-DAD8-CCDC-960413842BC0D478)